# Moving Website from Domain to another Domain

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, ftp, phpmyadmin, dns

I have a website with a wordpress backend. I wanted to move my website's data from its original domain to another new one. So, I downloaded the website's data and uploaded it to the new domain using FTP FileZilla. But after finishing this step, I checked the website with the new domain, and it tells me the following: "This site can’t be reached" and "mydomain.com’s server DNS address could not be found".
So, please, anyone guide what should I do/ and if there is a missing step or not. There is someone has told that there is a file should be downloaded from PHPMyAdmin. So, is that right or wrong? I don't. 
Your help will be so appreciated, as I couldn't find anyone to help for that.

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question. I'm assuming by "new domain", you mean new web host and domain name, but this is a tough question to answer. I reccomend you read the Moving Wordpress guide in the codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress. It's a very detailed guide that provides step by step instructions with several senarios. Also, "someone" is likely telling you that you can export/backup your database through PHPmyadmin and upload it to a new/different database. You can read more about that in the codex guide. Best of Luck.

Comment: thank you so much your provided link helped me alot.

Comment: You're welcome, i'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just your FTP files but also your database must be moved to a new location (if you are transferring hosts). Best to start again, using the wordpress export plugin, or use the popular Wordpress Backup plugins to totally export your site to a file... then upload / import to a new wordpress install on your new server. Just set up a blank wordpress install there to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I tried a wordpress plugin but it doesn't work (it's called "Backupbuddy"). That's I'm trying the hard way using FTP.